# Installation error when trying to install 14.10, 14.04 and 12.04 on my Dell XPS 15Z

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation, dell, 14.10

Specifications:

- Laptop Dell XPS 15z
- Core i7-2640M CPU 2.8
- HDD 750 GB
- 8 GB Ram

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.10, 14.04 and 12.04 without luck, all of them just hang when I press any keyboard letter, so I just use the touch pad or on-screen keyboard. External Keyboards aren't working but never mind I'm using an on-screen keyboard.

Furthermore, when it comes to installation it just stops with an "Error fsyncing/closing `/dev/sda` input/output error". I tried different USB drives, formatting the HDD using Disk Utility got an "error erasing helper exited with exit code 1 in part_del_partition". I tried `sudo swapoff /dev/sda`, but got an error "invalid arg". I also tried editing boot options with `acpi=off` or `acpi=noirq`, but that didn't help either.

Edit:
Now with a help of friends i managed to install another distro "LinuxMint" and the trick was adding a kernel parameter "`nox2apic`"

any help with the ubuntu distro ??

Answer (score 1):

just edit the kernel parameter when booting by pressing `e` in the grub menu.

then edit the line to the following from "`quiet splash`" to "`noapic quiet splash`"

then you should add it to your grub file after installation.